# Get Android resource ID from string in an adapter

Tags: android, json, android-resources

I'm trying to get Android resource ID and set ImageView src to that specific ID from a JSON array.

I'm using the following code

```
String str = mDataset.get(position).icon_res.substring(0, mDataset.get(position).icon_res.lastIndexOf('.'));
        int res = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("ic_" + str, "drawable", this.getClass().getPackage().getName());
        if(res == 0)
        {
            Log.d("is null", "null");
            Log.d("string = ", "ic_" + str);
            Log.d("package", this.getClass().getPackage().getName());
        }
```

But from some reason it's detecting the res int as 0. Package name seems correct, string is correct but for some reason it's not finding the correct drawable resource. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

```
Full adapter code

package com.xyz

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Kreso on 23.3.2017..
 */

public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>{


    private List<Category> mDataset;
    private Context context;

    public CategoryAdapter(List<Category> categoriesList) {
        mDataset = categoriesList;
    }


    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView txtHeader;
        public ConstraintLayout holderLayout;
        public ImageView icon;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            holderLayout = (ConstraintLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.itemHolder);
            icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            context = v.getContext();
        }
    }

    /*public void add(int position, String item) {
        mDataset.add(position, item);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }*/

    public void remove(int position) {
        mDataset.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataset.size());
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
   /* public CategoryAdapter(ArrayList<String> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }*/

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_row, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    final String name = mDataset.get(position).name;
        holder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position).name);
        //holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_beer);
        String str = mDataset.get(position).icon_res.substring(0, mDataset.get(position).icon_res.lastIndexOf('.'));
        int res = context.getResources().getSystem().getIdentifier("ic_" + str, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        if(res == 0)
        {
            Log.d("is null", "null");
            Log.d("string = ", "ic_" + str);
            Log.d("package", this.getClass().getPackage().getName());
        }

        holder.icon.setImageResource(res);
        holder.holderLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            remove(position);
        }
    });

}

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: share your full code of adapter

Comment: `Resources.getSystem()` is not your package's `Resources`. That's why it's not finding your identifiers.

Comment: @MikeM. What should I use then? It's kind of a confusing and I'm doing this for the first time. My answer gave me the required result, but if your soultion is better I'd like to know more regarding the background.

Comment: Narendra Sorathiya's answer shows how to get your `Resources`. That is, you need to call `getResources()` on a `Context` in your app. Your way works too, though, so whichever you want. I was just explaining why your original code was failing.

Comment: @MikeM. I took Narendra's answer, it's cleaner and it was a silly mistake in the first place. Thanks for the help both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve it by using a slightly different approach

```
// Remove file extension
        String str = mDataset.get(position).icon_res.substring(0, mDataset.get(position).icon_res.lastIndexOf('.'));
        // Replace - with underscore _
        str = str.replace("-", "_");

        int res = 0;
        // Try to find the resource with that name (icons in drawable folder)
        try {
            res = R.drawable.class.getField("ic_" + str).getInt(null);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            // if no icon is found
            holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_coffee);
        }
        // Set icon resource
        holder.icon.setImageResource(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

use this code, to get image from Resources :

```
int res = context.getResources().getIdentifier("ic_" + str, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```